# Firebase v3.1 Web SDK - Github oAuth Not Working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm not gonna post a bunch of code, unless I have to.  It's mostly pasted straight from Firebase.google.com.  I got every authentication method working fine but Github oAuth is all kinds of screwed up. So after a while I decided to go from Firebase v3.0 to 3.1.  No fix.

The redirect page does pop up but I can't use my regular Github credentials - the Github account used to create the developer app (even though I log out of Github in my other web tab.  My `authAction()` catch says:

> An account already exists with the same email address but different
>   sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this
>   email address.

So, I created a second dummy Github account and I now can log in using that.  However upon logging in, `user.email` and `user.displayName` come back `null`.

Another strange thing: When logged out of every app, I log in to my Firebase app via Github oAuth and then open a new tab and navigate to Github, I'm already logged in!  Presumably, somehow my token is shared between websites?  Google, Facebook, Twitter, Anon, and Email/Pwd all work fine.

Anyone have this Github oAuth issue too or is it just me?...

Answer (score 2):

When you get the error:
An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address.
It means you already signed in using the same email with a different provider. You can sign in to the same provider and then link the github account to that current user. You can call `firebase.auth(().currentUser.link(githubCred)` or `firebase.auth(().currentUser.linkWithPopup/Redirect(githubProvider)`

As for Github not providing your email and name, you could have your github account settings set to not disclose your email and info. Typically you have to ask for the `user:email` oauth scope if you are using `signInWithPopup`/`signInWithRedirect` but that is currently not working with Firebase. The team is working on a fix.

Regarding your third issue, I am not sure I understand this correctly. When you sign in to Firebase using Github or any other provider, you will need to login to that provider before consenting to that app's permissions. If you navigate to that provider's site, it is normal to be logged in. If you try to sign in with Firebase using github on a different app, you would still be logged in to github but you would be asked to consent to that app's new permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I know my app is logged out of all providers when my issue happens (via the .onAuthStateChanged method).  user.email does work except for Facebook, in which case you have to ask them for elevated oAuth access.  I dunno - I'll circle back when I get back to auth.  I've moved on to developing other parts of my app now.